# How to call view from the view in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have two view files views.js and views2.js .On button click  views.js call.On views.js there is a button that needs to triggers views2.js.But the problem is that on button click views2.js
is not working.

I have written some code.
In views.js

```
define( ["backbone"], function(Backbone) {

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.model.get("desc") + "<button id='btn2' class='btn btn-             primary'>Next Page</button>");
        return this;
    }
});

var NextPageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': 'firstquestion'
    },

    render: function(){        
        return this;
    },

    firstquestion: function(){
        //to solve circular dependency
        require(['routes'],function(routes){
            var router = routes.pageRouter;
            router.navigate('view', {trigger: true});
       });   
    }
 });
    var views2 = require("views2");//should I call views2 here
    var np2 = new views2.NextPageView2({el: $("#btn2")});
 return {
    UserView: UserView,
    NextPageView: NextPageView
 };
});
```

In views2.js

```
define( ["backbone"], function(Backbone) {
var UserView2 = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    render: function(){

        this.$el.html(this.model.get("desc") + "<button id='btn3' class='btn btn-primary'>Next Page</button>");
        return this;
    }
});

var NextPageView2 = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': 'secondquestion'
    },
    render: function(){
        return this;
    },
    secondquestion: function(){
        require(['routes2'],function(routes2){
            var router = routes2.pageRouter2;
            router.navigate('view', {trigger: true});
        });
    }
});
return {
    UserView2: UserView2,
    NextPageView2: NextPageView2
};
});
```

Comment: try calling code - `var views2 = require("views2");
    var np2 = new views2.NextPageView2({el: this.$("#btn2")});` inside render of view.js . See if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a Require.js dependency on the calling view.

Comment: views: {
      deps: ["jquery","underscore", "backbone","views2"]}        should i write like this in congig.js